# Simple Question: How to simplify what is inside the Sin function like below?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

I have this code of Mathematica

```
(1/(2 (fj - fk) π))
 Cos[(fj - fk) π T + (fj - fk) π (T + δt)] Sin[(fj - 
       fk) π T - (fj - fk) π (T + δt)]
```

[image]

There are a few terms inside these Sin functions that if multiplied can be canceled out, Can someone tell me how to simplify this expression in Mathematica? TrigReduce, simply, Fullsimply didn't work here.

Comment: I encounter many equations like this that I need to solve

Comment: Are you aware of functions like `TrigReduce`, `TrigExpand`, `TrigToExp`, and `ExpToTrig`?

Comment: Yes but my application is different, I want this exact equation for representation purpose so I want Mathematica to simply what is inside this cos and sin for me. The above function changes everything by giving it another shape.@mmeent

Comment: tried `Simplify`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
expr=(1/(2 (fj - fk) π)) Cos[(fj - fk) π T + (fj - 
   fk) π (T + δt)] Sin[(fj - fk) π T - (fj - 
   fk) π (T + δt)];
expr /. (f : Cos | Sin)[a_] :>  f[Simplify[a]]
```

This applies `Simplify` only to the arguments of `Sin` and `Cos`

Alternatively,

```
Simplify[expr,Trig->False]
```

(This prevents Mathematica from applying Trig manipulations during `Simplify`

Comment: I have expertise in wireless communication and I only know MATLAB, has no idea how you did this? 
Can you do the same for cos term, like both sin and cos?

Comment: Why not simplify the whole expression using SImplify["your expression"]

Comment: @DanielHuber Because the OP has indicated that they want to keep the overall functional form of the expression. (By default, Simplify will re-express the given expression as a sum of two trig functions rather than the product as given.)